# What are the meaning of "There you got", "Here you are", "There you are" and "There you go"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I would like to know where and when we use these phrases.

> 1. There you got
> 2. Here you are
> 3. There you are
> 4. There you go

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Hello AH., for having a constructive answer you have to pose a constructive question, otherwise there is the danger no one can help you. Hence, try editing adding some example sentences in which you want to use those expressions. Stay with us, and don't discourage if your question will be early closed.

Comment: a) "There you got" is not to my knowledge an English idiom; do you perhaps mean "There you got me"? b) The other three each have one idiomatic sense in which the three are interchangeable, but also have distinct literal senses. Cataloguing all that would really be more than one answer could helpfully handle.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I would never use (1) in any situation.

I would use the rest in various different situations, but I'm guessing from your question that you're referring to a situation where you might have handed somebody something, or just completed a task for them.

In that situation, I would personally use (4), but it would be fine to use (2) or (3) also.

In different situations, all 3 would not be appropriate, but it just depends on the situation.